# itemize option \item[ ]

Tags: itemize

I am trying to understand how \item[ ] works in the itemize environment, and I get confused why \item[[1].] gives

[1 .]

I was assuming \item[whatever it is.] gives

whatever it is.

Could anyone help explain this? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Optional arguments cannot contain `]`, unless it is braced, without confusing the absorption of the optional argument.

Here I insert a large `labelsep` so that you can clearly see what is interpreted as the label versus the item.  In the first case, the internal `]` triggers the end of the optional argument, because balancing of `[...]` does not occur by default with TeX, since they are catcode-12.  Only catcode-1,2 tokens `{...}` are enforcably balanced during argument absorption.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}[labelsep=.5in]
\item[[1].]x 
\item[{[1]}.]x 
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah I see! Thanks!